# If a graph has an order of 1001 and each of its vertices has a minimum degree of 500, prove that the diameter of the graph is 2 or less.

Tags: graph-theory

I know that, in the case that two vertices of the graph were adjacent, the diameter would be one, but I don't know how to find out the diameter of the graph if two vertices were not adjacent.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is show that for any two vertices which are not adjacent, they have a common neighbour (so there is a path of length $2$ between them). Can you see how to do this using the fact that each has at least $500$ neighbours?